# Trouble installing ubuntu from live usb on a windows 8 laptop

Tags: boot, windows-8, uefi, live-usb

I have an asus laptop with windows 8 preinstalled on it. I dual booted it last year and everything worked. then the windows 8 side totally crashed. if it lets me in at all, all I see is the home screen but with no live tiles or anything. Now I want to totally wipe the HDD and install the latest ubuntu LTS. this is where I am having problems. I created a live USB stick and have been trying to boot into that but I keep getting boot error and nothing happens. I have disabled fast boot, and I am pretty sure that I disabled the safe boot as well. this is different from other cases because I can not get into the UEFI BIOS screen at all. the computer does currently have a working ubuntu 12.04 partition. I have no idea what to do. please help.

Comment: You need to go to the BIOS first and disable anything that has to do with UEFI (as you don't have the UEFI partition any more) then set the boot order manually to USB only and then boot into the USB.